# Increase timeout duration for resolving endpoints

Tags: angular

I am connecting to an endpoint which takes a very long time to respond. 5 minutes can be expected. I would like to know how I can set the default timeout on the frontend of my application. Currently the endpoint will timeout at 2 minutes.

I tried adding a proxy.conf.json file inmy src folder with the following

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://prodAPIURL",
    "secure": false,
    "timeout": 600000
  }
}
```

Also I added a line to my Angular.json file

```
 "proxyConfig": "./projects/afdigitalexperience/src/proxy.conf.json"
```

This does not seem to be working though.

Is there something I am potentially missing or is there another way to increase the waiting time for an endpoint to resolve?

Comment: 5 min. is too long, not recommended at all. Why not you split the response into chunks and fetch?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes I know it is too long but this is what I get unfortunately. The backend is being optimized but it will take a while before that can be done so I was hoping to do a temporary workaround.